# FxCop in MSBuild and disabling CA0060 exceptions

Tags: msbuild, fxcop

I am very new to MSBuild and it is taking me a little while to work out how to do things.

So I am trying to integrate FxCop into my project to be automatically run when I build them on the build server.

At the moment the way to go seems to be to add a custom task to the build that you call when you build. So I have so far created the following:

```
<Target Name="ExecuteFxCop">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="bin\XXXX.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Call the task using a collection of files and all default rules -->
  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop 
  TaskAction="Analyse" 
  Files="@(Files)" 
  SearchGac="True"
  OutputFile="FxCopReport.xml">
  </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop>
</Target>
```

However when I run this `>msbuild XXXX.csproj /t:ExecuteFxCop` it fails with error 512 which I have narrowed down to an exception from indirectly-referenced assemblys:

```
<Exception Keyword="CA0060" Kind="Engine" TreatAsWarning="True">
  <Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException</Type>
  <ExceptionMessage>The indirectly-referenced Silverlight assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' could not be found. This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results could be incomplete. Silverlight reference assemblies should be specified with the '/reference' switch. This assembly was referenced by: XXX\bin\ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.dll.</ExceptionMessage>
</Exception>
```

But I cannot add this reference. Is there a way to get the build to see this reference or preferably just disable the error altogether?

I did try: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/c6780439-bc04-459e-80c3-d1712b2f5456/ but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the work-around here: http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/07/12/avoiding-fxcop-warning-ca0060.aspx

**Edit**

For example, using the FxCop MsBuild task, set ContinueOnError and check the ExitCode as follows:

```
<Target Name="ExecuteFxCop">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="bin\XXXX.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- Call the task using a collection of files and all default rules -->
  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop 
  TaskAction="Analyse" 
  Files="@(Files)" 
  SearchGac="True"
  OutputFile="FxCopReport.xml"
  ContinueOnError="WarnAndContinue">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ExitCode"/>
  </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.CodeQuality.FxCop>

  <Error Condition="$(ExitCode) != 512" Text="FxCop failed with exit code: $(ExitCode)"/>

</Target>
```

P.S. (This is not tested)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It seems that as I don't run FxCop via a post build step that this won't work though but it might be that I need to change to run FxCop like this instead to get rid of the errors. We shall see.

Comment: Right.  In the mean time, you can create a new feature request to ignore specific error codes here: http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: @alexjamesbrown, I've updated my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution but what usually works for me is adding the

```
fxcop cmd-option /d:{dir-of-random-assemblies}
```

which essentially tells fxcop to look in that additional directory for assemblies. 
Adding a reference to a proj that doesn't need it is a bad idea in my opinion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb429449(v=vs.80).aspx